# customize the logo image dosbox in gui "dosbox_splash.h"

Tags: c++, gimp, splash-screen, dosbox

i need customize the logo image dosbox in gui "dosbox_splash.h", but the format is .h

like this ---

```
static const struct {
  unsigned int   width;
  unsigned int   height;
  unsigned int   bytes_per_pixel; /* 3:RGB, 4:RGBA */
  unsigned char  rle_pixel_data[24875 + 1];
} gimp_image = {
  640, 400, 3,
  "\377\272=\0\377\272=\0\377\272=\0\377\272=\0\377\272=\0\377\272=\0\377\272"
  "=\0\377\272=\0\377\272=\0\377\272=\0\377\272=\0\377\272=\0\377\272=\0\377"
  "\272=\0\377\272=\0\377\272=\0\377\272=\0\377\272=\0\377\272=\0\377\272=\0"
  "\377\272=\0\377\272=\0\377\272=\0\377\272=\0\377\272=\0\377\272=\0\377\272"
  "=\0\377\272=\0\377\272=\0\377\272=\0\377\272=\0\377\272=\0\377\272=\0\377"
  "\272=\0\377\272=\0\377\272=\0\377\272=\0\377\272=\0\377\272=\0\377\272=\0"
  "\377\272=\0\377\272=\0\377\272=\0\377\272=\0\377\272=\0\377\272=\0\377\272"
  "=\0\377\272=\0\377\272=\0\377\272=\0\377\272=\0\377\272=\0\377\272=\0\377"
  "\272=\0\377\272=\0\377\272=\0\377\272=\0\377\272=\0\377\272=\0\377\272=\0"
  "\377\272=\0\377\272=\0\377\272=\0\377\272=\0\377\272=\0\377\272=\0\377\272"
  "=\0\377\272=\0\377\272=\0\377\272=\0\377\272=\0\377\272=\0\377\272=\0\377"
  "\272=\0\377\272=\0\377\272=\0\377\272=\0\377\272=\0\377\272=\0\377\272=\0"
  "\377\272=\0\377\272=\0\377\272=\0\377\272=\0\377\272=\0\377\272=\0\377\272"
  "=\0\377\272=\0\377\272=\0\377\272=\0\377\272=\0\377\272=\0\377\272=\0\377"
  "\272=\0\377\272=\0\377\272=\0\377\272=\0\377\272=\0\377\272=\0\377\272=\0"
  "\377\272=\0\377\272=\0\377\272=\0\377\272=\0\377\272=\0\377\272=\0\377\272"
  "=\0\377\272=\0\377\272=\0\377\272=\0\377\272=\0\377\272=\0\377\272=\0\377"
  "\272=\0\377\272=\0\377\272=\0\377\272=\0\377\272=\0\377\272=\0\377\272=\0"
  "\377\272=\0\377\272=\0\377\272=\0\377\272=\0\377\272=\0\377\272=\0\377\272"
  "=\0\377\272=\0\377\272=\0\377\272=\0\377\272=\0\377\272=\0\377\272=\0\377"
```

i use gimp for windows and not create the same format, when compile have the error 
initializer string for array of chars is too long

my format

```
static const struct {
  unsigned int   width;
  unsigned int   height;
  unsigned int   bytes_per_pixel; /* 2:RGB16, 3:RGB, 4:RGBA */ 
  unsigned char  pixel_data[640 * 400 * 3 + 1];
} gimp_image = {
  640, 400, 3,
  "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"
  "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"
  "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"
  "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"
  "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"
  "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"
  "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"
  "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"
  "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"
  "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"
  "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"
  "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"
  "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"
  "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"
  "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"
  "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"
  "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"
  "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"
  "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"
  "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"
  "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"
  "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"
  "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"
  "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"
  "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"
"\1\1\1\1\1\1\1\1\1\1\1\1\1\1\1\1\1\1\1\1\1\1\1\1\1\1\1\1\1\1\1\1\1\1\1\1"
  "\1\1\1\1\1\1\1\1\1\1\1\3\1\4\2\0\3\2\2\4\0\0\4\1\4\11\34!%\341\346\352\365"
  "\375\377\367\377\377\357\364\367\373\377\377\367\371\370\377\376\374\377"
  "\374\371\377\373\367\374\367\363\245\240\234#\40\33\5\1\0\1\0\0\5\3\4\0\0"
  "\2\10\10\12\3\4\10\1\2\6\1\2\6\1\2\6\0\1\3\1\1\1\1\1\1\1\1\0\2\1\0\2\0\3"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using Gimp you may want to export your image to "C source code". You then get an option dialog where you can check "Use 1 byte Run-Length-Encoding" (which is what the data in rle_pixel_data is encoded with as well). Using the "C source code header" exporter doesn't give you that option resulting in way larger image data strings.

Comment: finaly can make a pic in h format and compile...but Now shows again fatal error C1091: compiler limit: string exceeds 65535 bytes in length

Answer (score 0):

or take a look at http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1140406 it looks like converting tool from images to rle...